# Does anyone understand .rain? Display 4th lvl Category pages

Tags: php

I am trying to display 3rd lvl Category pages on top level category pages as can be seen here - https://www.waterstreetgallery.co.uk/en/exhibitions/past/

Inside the page 2019 I need to display the category there /february-march/

https://www.waterstreetgallery.co.uk/en/exhibitions/past/2019/february-march/

Theres an image added to the category already so with the new / altered code the image thumbnail should automatically appear.

```
    <!-- 1stlevel -->
  {% for category in shop.categories %}
    {% if category.id == collection.category_id and category.subs %}
    <div class="parenter grid-cell mb3 {% if category.url == exhibitions %}exhibitionsGrid{% endif %}">
      <div class="grid column-orient">
        <div class="grid-cell">
          <div class="grid wrap col-filtered relative">
          {% for sub in category.subs %}
          {% if sub.image %}
          <div class="grid-cell grow0 col-products_product already-visible come-in">
            <div class="subcatimage">
              <a href="{{ sub.url | url }}">
                <img class="image" src="{{ sub.image | url_image() }}">
                <div>{{ sub.title | t }}</div>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>         
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
    <!-- 1stlevel -->
    <!--  2ndlevel  -->
  {% set collectionTitle = collection.internal.url | split('/') %}
  {% if collectionTitle[1] %}
  {% for category in shop.categories %}
  {% for subCat in category.subs %}
  {% if subCat.id == collection.category_id and subCat.subs %}
  <div class="parenter grid-cell mb3 {% if category.url == exhibitions %}exhibitionsGrid{% endif %}">
    <div class="grid column-orient">
      <div class="grid-cell">
        <div class="grid wrap col-filtered relative">
        {% for sub in subCat.subs %}
        {% if sub.image %}
        <div class="grid-cell grow0 col-products_product already-visible come-in">
          <div class="subcatimage">
            <a href="{{ sub.url | url }}">
              <img class="image" src="{{ sub.image | url_image() }}">
              <div>{{ sub.title | t }}</div>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>    
  {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
    <!--  2ndlevel  -->
```

I don't know .rain

With the correct code the image found here - https://www.waterstreetgallery.co.uk/en/exhibitions/past/2019/february-march/

will display on the page /2019

Comment: I think it has something to do with this - {% for sub in subCat.subs %} and bringing in the next level above on the next page - subsubCat.subs ???

Comment: You’ll get better help if you label the post with the right language.  This isn’t php